# How do I create a dynamodb schema with nested attribute definitions via aws-cli?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I have been using the command `aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json` to create local dynamodb tables for testing on my local box.

I can create simple tables but I cannot create more complex, real world tables. I looked through the AWS documentation and it's missing the explanation for nested AttributeDefinitions, or I could not find it. 
Here's a simple example that works (for creation through the AWS CLI):

```
{
  "TableName": "fruitsTable",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "fruitId",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "fruitId",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
  }
}
```

That works fine. `aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file:///Users/you/subfile/server/config/tables/fruits.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

However I would like to see an example of creating an object that is more complex. What schema would work for this?

```
{
  "ComplexFruit" : [
    {
      "complexFruitId": "redbanana-fromGroceryStore"
      "name" : "redBanana", 
      "notes": "this one is red",
      "count" : {
        "ripe" : 5,
        "total": 10
       },
      "stores" : [ 
          {"storeName" : "Exito"}
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

I am stumped on how I can create a nested `AttributeDefinition` without a ton of guessing or digging through the code (if dynamodb is open source?).
 Does anyone know? Also this obviously a contrived example but it would demonstrate how to create nested schemas.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to specify `AttributeDefinitions` for attributes that will be part of the table's primary key or part of an index's key. Dynamo is mostly schemaless (other than the key definitons). It doesn't care about any of the other attributes you want to store - there is no need to model anything.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Okay I guess this is something I just misunderstood because I come from a SQL world. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit learning, I will share some that I have learned, and during the process of learning about DynamoDb, I played with a couple of ORMs.

Dynamoose documentation is terrible, I got it working through a lot of trial and error. AWS documentation is bad but do-able. This is what I was looking for from the beginning https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js

Hopefully this will be a shortcut for other devs looking into using DynamoDb with ORM on Nodejs

Comment: I had the exact same feeling about the `data-mapper`. Dynamoose seems a bit better now, but still has major gaps in the docs.